# Get keycloak.json dynamically?

Tags: javascript, docker, security, keycloak

From the official [documentation page of Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/securing_apps/topics/oidc/javascript-adapter.html) it is suggested to download the keycloak.json from "Installation"-Tab after you create a keycloak client and save that where your HTML-Page is located so you can use that to initialize the JavaScript Keycloak adapter.

I wonder if I could access keycloak.json directly from keycloak without saving it first on my project?

(I'm using dockers and the URL of the the HTML-Application has always different URL-s and parameters)

Comment: Do you want to make some kind of on-the-fly configuration? What do you mean with `without saving it first on my project`?

Comment: @Xtreme Biker Depending on the installation of our Application (That contains many smaller Applications that are connected to one keycloak) the host and port of the keycloak und UI-Application are always (for each installation) different. And those Application-s are running in dockers, so the User that is installing the Applications doesn't have the possibility after configuring the keycloak to add than the keycloak.json in the UI-Application that is in docker. That's why would be nice If the UI could access the keycloak.json directly from keycloak.

Comment: So the UI shouldn't know about the keycloak host and port before being launched? How do you want to retrieve this info from keycloak if the app doesn't know where keycloak is at first?

Comment: That's a good point but anyway my first  thoughts about this were like this: The Keycloak and UI have the same Host (so I can read the host from the url) only the port is different from UI and always the same, moreover the keycloak client id for the ui and the realm is always the same too so theoretically I could use something like: https://myuihost:8843/auth/myrealm/uiclientid/keycloak-json

Comment: I've never used the JS adapter myself, so can't tell you. But probably with the tool you use to pack your web application you can switch the keycloak.json files being chosen.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't have fixed keycloak.json files, but maybe I need to thing more about my approach, maybe there is no way around it to serve it from the server dynamically. Thank you anyway!